# Fire and forget?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, icommand

I have a asyncRelayCommand in a c# wpf mvvm application that does not work i kinda understand that i need a method for this but the guide i went through does not mention how to make one https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/ that is the guide i went through and here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace DataConverter.Command
{

    public interface IAsyncCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        Task ExecuteAsync(T parameter);
        bool CanExecute(T parameter);
    }

    public class AsyncCommand<T> : IAsyncCommand<T>
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        private bool _isExecuting;
        private readonly Func<T, Task> _execute;
        private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;
        private readonly IErrorHandler _errorHandler;

        public AsyncCommand(Func<T, Task> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute = null, IErrorHandler errorHandler = null)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
            _errorHandler = errorHandler;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(T parameter)
        {
            return !_isExecuting && (_canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true);
        }

        public async Task ExecuteAsync(T parameter)
        {
            if (CanExecute(parameter))
            {
                try
                {
                    _isExecuting = true;
                    await _execute(parameter);
                }
                finally
                {
                    _isExecuting = false;
                }
            }

            RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        #region Explicit implementations
        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return CanExecute((T)parameter);
        }

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ExecuteAsync((T)parameter).FireAndForgetSafeAsync(_errorHandler);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Can anyone show me how i can make one so this will work i really do not understand why the guide does not mention it but yea

Comment: Waht du you mean with: "*i need a method*"???. He is mentioning it:  Submit = new AsyncCommand(ExecuteSubmitAsync, CanExecuteSubmit);

Comment: but my fire and async give me an error

Comment: or are you saying that using it would get rid of the error

Comment: Do you mean the SafeFireAndForget Method?

Comment: FireAndForgetSafeAsync

Comment: He is pointing on this: https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices

Comment: Ýou are saying that i should download the library i have done so and it does not eaven use it so not sure of what you mean otherwise

Comment: for async commands I highly recommend [ReactiveCommand](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/) implementation. It has all edge cases already implemented and once you go reactive. it's hard to look back at "normal" code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really quick goole seach: https://www.google.de/search?q=FireAndForgetSafeAsync

=> https://johnthiriet.com/removing-async-void/

```
public static class TaskUtilities
{

    public static async void FireAndForgetSafeAsync(this Task task, IErrorHandler handler = null)
    {
       try
       {
           await task;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           handler?.HandleError(ex);
       }
   }
}
```